# Valores de un Select - Javascript

Tags: javascript, select

**Sin poder modificar el HTML, solamente con Javascript** realizar la siguiente operación:

Tengo un SELECT con cuatro posibilidades:

```
<select name="tipo" id="tipo">
    <option selected value="none">Elige uno...</option>         
    <option value="rock">Rock</option>
    <option value="pop">Pop</option>
    <option value="punk">Punk</option>
    <option value="indie">Indie</option>
</select>
```

A la hora de enviar un formulario, NO me tiene que permitir enviarlo si elijo la primera opción, por defecto, cuyo texto es: "Elige uno...". ¿Cómo podría controlarse eso?

**Código:**

```
//Función que comprueba que no se elige la opción por defecto "Elige uno...".
function comprobarTipo(){
    if (!document.getElementById("tipo").value=="none"){ //Para comparar con el texto sería: .text="Elige uno..."
        var tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo TIPO debe elegir una opción.";
        document.getElementById("tipo").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Elija la opción que elija me muestra "El campo TIPO debe elegir una opción." en todas las opciones. ¿A qué se debe?**

Comment: Crea un [mcve] para ver cómo funciona `comprobarTipo`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Funciona cómo el ejemplo que has puesto pero sin utilizar HTML5 ni editar el HTML. Únicamente utilizando Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se puede controlar sin necesidad de JavaScript, sólo con HTML y la propiedad `required` de los campos para hacerlos obligatorios. Lo que tendrías que hacer es:

1. Hacer que el `select` sea obligatorio poniéndole el atributo `required`
2. Cambiar el valor de la opción "Elige uno..." de "none" a simplemente "" (cadena vacía)

Si el navegador soporta HTML5 y `required` (todos los navegadores modernos), se encargará de que el formulario no se pueda enviar hasta que esa lista desplegable tenga un valor válido (diferente de "").

Demo:

```html
<form>
  <select name="tipo" id="tipo" required>
    <option selected value="">Elige uno...</option>
    <option value="rock">Rock</option>
    <option value="pop">Pop</option>
    <option value="punk">Punk</option>
    <option value="indie">Indie</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

---

Ahora, si no quieres cambiar el HTML como pones en los comentarios abajo, y lo que quieres es solucionar la función JavaScript, el problema es fácil de identificar: El `if` en el que haces la comparación es un poco raro y falla. Ahora mismo haces:

```
if (!document.getElementById("tipo").value=="none"){
```

Esa mezcla de `!`, variable, comparación y valor no es buena. Parece que la precedencia de operadores te está jugando una mala pasada (se está ejecutando `!document.getElementById("tipo").value` antes de la comparación `==` y por eso siempre va a ser falso). En su lugar debería ser:

```
if (document.getElementById("tipo").value!="none"){
```

Y ya funciona como puedes ver en esta demo:

```js
function comprobarTipo() {
  if (document.getElementById("tipo").value != "none") { //Para comparar con el texto sería: .text="Elige uno..."
    var tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML = "El campo TIPO debe elegir una opción.";
    document.getElementById("tipo").focus();
    return false;
  }
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
    <option selected value="none">Elige uno...</option>
    <option value="rock">Rock</option>
    <option value="pop">Pop</option>
    <option value="punk">Punk</option>
    <option value="indie">Indie</option>
  </select>
  <div id="errores"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Es obligatorio hacerlo usando Javascript, no se puede editar el HTML que te ofrecen. Ahí mi duda.

Comment: Esa parte no viene en la pregunta ;)

Comment: @omaza1990 respuesta editada. El problema de tu función es la comparación que no es buena

Comment: Efectivamente. Tenía mal programada la condición del "if". Problema resuelto. Thanks.

Comment: Ademas añadiria el atributo `disabled` a la linea `<option selected value="none">Elige uno...</option>` haciendo así que esta opción no aparezca en el desplegable, aunque eso depende del tipo de aplicación que se este montando.